# Regarding continuity for $f(x) = xe^x - 2$

Tags: calculus, continuity

Which of the following is false regarding $f(x) = xe^x - 2$:

a) the function $f(x)$ is well defined and continuous for all $x$ in the interval $(0,2)$
b) the function $f(x)$ has no discontinuity and no singularities
c) the function $f'(x)$ is well defined and continuous for all $x$ in the interval $(0,2)$
d) the function $f'(x)$ has no discontinuity and no singularities
e) all of the above

When I draw the graph for both $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ they both seem well defined and continuous on $(0,2)$ so I guess it's not a and c. However both seems to shoot up into infinity between 3 and 4. Does this mean both of them have singularities? Which in turn mean there is no correct option? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What do you mean ? $f(x) =xe^{x-2}$ or $f(x) =xe^x-2$  ?

Comment: @maksim, the latter.

Comment: @Martin R, you have a point. Thanks for the links.

Comment: The [exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function) grows very fast  for large $x$, but is defined, continuous, and (infinitely often) differentiable on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: It seems that the option “none of the above” is missing. The function is indeed everywhere infinitely differentiable, but one can consider it as defined over $(0,2)$ nonetheless, so I'd deem a and c true.

Comment: You are right. There is no correct option.

Comment: None of the options are correct. I suspect the question meant either to ask which of the following are true or have the last answer say none of the above.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the option "None of the above" should have appeared instead of "all of the above". Both f(x) and f'(x) are continuous and well defined on (0,2). Neither of them contain any discontinuities or singularities on $\Bbb R$ so none of the options are false.